# How is Spring.net for aspect oriented programming or do you recommend any other?

Tags: c#, spring.net, aop

I wanted to select a Framework for writing crosscutting functionality in my project. like logging etc. And I thought to use Aspect oriented programming. I found Spring.net after R&D. Can you please share your experience with advantages and Disadvantages or any other way you like? Or do you recommend any other framework? Your help and recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific programming questions - it isn't intended for discussions, recommendations, reviews, etc.  See the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp) just announced v2.  I have trialled PostShart 1.5, but dropped it when I couldn't get it to play nice with the MS Performance testing tools (which also inject code into the compiled assembly).

I liked the PostShart API and found it easy to follow, but the increased compile time could have potentially been an issue (we have large projects).

Comment: I checked it too. But its too expensive. 2000+ $ for 7 developers. Is there any cheaper alternative?

Comment: @Saghar: Ah, Postsharp 1.5 was GPL, didn't realise they'd gone commercial with 2.0! http://www.sharpcrafters.com/downloads/postsharp-1.5/rtm

@Steven : I'm afraid I don't know.